# ASP.NET MVC 4: Nested JSON with inconsistent Keys

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a novice with MVC and SO, so please forgive any ignorance I show.

I'm trying to deserialize some complex JSON from an API response and I've run into a roadblock.

**Here's the JSON response in question:**

```
{  
   "attendeeid":"1234567",
   "registrationstatus":"Incomplete",
   "testregistration":"1",
   "category":{  
      "categoryid":"2345678",
      "name":"WOC\/HOST"
   },
   "subcategory":"",
   "approvalstatus":"",
   "discountcode":"",
   "individualcost":"0.00",
   "groupcount":1,
   "cost":"0.00",
   "totalcost":"0.00",
   "received":"0.00",
   "imiscontactid":null,
   "recordid":"IhqeuIbQ4\/nj39Ew==",
   "responses":{  
      "66":{  
         "questionid":"7583398",
         "fieldname":"checkin",
         "name":"Check-in Date",
         "pageid":"5",
         "page":"Hotel",
         "choicekey":"0000-00-00",
         "response":"0000-00-00"
      },
      "67":{  
         "questionid":"7583399",
         "fieldname":"checkout",
         "name":"Check-out Date",
         "pageid":"5",
         "page":"Hotel",
         "choicekey":"0000-00-00",
         "response":"0000-00-00"
      },
      "77":{  
         "questionid":"7583409",
         "fieldname":"departuredate1",
         "name":"Departure Date",
         "pageid":"6",
         "page":"Travel",
         "choicekey":"0000-00-00",
         "response":"0000-00-00"
      },
      "83":{  
         "questionid":"7583415",
         "fieldname":"departuredate2",
         "name":"Arrival Date",
         "pageid":"6",
         "page":"Travel",
         "choicekey":"0000-00-00",
         "response":"0000-00-00"
      },
      "90":{  
         "questionid":"7583422",
         "fieldname":"arrivaldate",
         "name":"Arrival Date",
         "pageid":"6",
         "page":"Travel",
         "choicekey":"0000-00-00",
         "response":"0000-00-00"
      },
      "96":{  
         "questionid":"7583428",
         "fieldname":"departuredate",
         "name":"Departure Date",
         "pageid":"6",
         "page":"Travel",
         "choicekey":"0000-00-00",
         "response":"0000-00-00"
      }
   },
   "created":"2015-07-27 14:33:54",
   "language":"eng",
   "tax":"0.00",
   "statetax":"0.00",
   "categorycost":"0.00",
   "subcategorycost":"0.00",
   "agendacost":"0.00",
   "optioncost":"0.00",
   "hotelcost":"0.00",
   "guestcost":"0.00",
   "adjustments":"0.00",
   "lastmodified":"2015-07-27 14:33:54",
   "checkindate":"",
   "invoicelink":"https:\/\/www.website.com\/pdfinvoice.php?id=IsjfdAdf%fake%sgS%%dfaseijD\/bQ4%D"
}
```

In my original testing of the API, the data under "responses" was always an array of objects containing the "questionid", "approvalstatus" etc. But in further testing I received the above response where "responses" isn't an array, but a series of pairs with inconsistent keys.

**Here is my current model:**

```
public class Respons {
    [Key]
    [Column("QuestionID")]
    public string questionid { get; set; }

    public string EventID { get { return Controllers.RequestQueueController.GetEventID(); } set { } }

    public int AttendeeID { get { return int.Parse(Controllers.RequestQueueController.GetAttID()); } set { } }

    [Column("QuestionText")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Column("AnswerText")]
    public object response { get; set; }
}

public class Answer {
    public string AnswerID { get; set; }

    public string EventID { get { return Controllers.RequestQueueController.GetEventID(); } set { } }

    [Column("AttendeeID")]
    public int attendeeid { get; set; }

    public List<Respons> responses { get; set; }

    [Column("AnsweredDate")]
    public string created { get; set; }

    [Column("ModifiedDate")]
    public string lastmodified { get; set; }
}
```

**TL;DR**

- The "responses" data in the JSON response is sometimes an array of pairs, and sometimes a collection of pairs with inconsistent keys
- I have a model that works with the arrays, but not the collection of pairs with inconsistent keys, and I'm unsure how to edit the model to support both

**My question:**
How can I deserialize complex JSON with inconsistent type and key names into a Model in MVC?

Comment: OK, so... question. Why are the responses different? Are you retrieving from 2 different external sources by chance?

Comment: @tsacodes To be honest, I don't know why they're different.  It's the same call, the only difference in the call being the attendeeID.  I've gone over the data within the responses and don't see why it would be returned in this manner vs the array.  

I reached out to my contact at the company in charge of the API, and he said he'd noticed if before but didn't seem concerned because it deserializes fine in PHP.  He opened a ticket for me, but I'm looking to resolve it as soon as possible.